# C# List Iteration Issues On Second Iteration

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm attempting to uncover a value from a list and use it for some computations, but I need to iterate through the list twice. It seems as if when I iterate through the second time, the value is always empty.

I've tried a few different approaches...

I've tried a foreach loop with the following syntax

```
foreach (var x in components) {

    var test = x;
    var matCompId = x.MatCompId;

}
```

I've tried using a while loop as well...

```
int i = 0;

while (i < components.Count()) {

    var test = components.ElementAt(i);
    var matCompId = test.MatCompId;
    var matCompIdTwo = components.ElementAt(i).MatCompId;
    var testTwo = components[i];
    var matCompIdThree = testTwo.MatCompId;
    var matCompIdFour = components[i].MatCompId;

}
```

Same result each time.... test/testTwo is null and the matCompId is always a null exception. I don't want to handle the null exception by using Default(), as I need that to break so that it can return an error message to the UI accordingly.

This is a really large function so I can't quite copy all of it, but here is a more detailed snippet of code... (I only provided the parts that are crucial to this question). I was thinking that I just could not iterate through the list twice as it might be discarded after it had been iterated through once, but that doesn't seem to be the case as the list has information in it when inspecting it during a debug session.

```
//get material comp measure.
var compMeasure = (
    from mat in dat2.tblMaterials
    where mat.MaterialId == obj.CoLocMatId
    select mat.CompMeasure
).FirstOrDefault();

//get material components
var components = (
    from locmat in dat2.tblCoLocMat
    join mat in dat2.tblMaterials on locmat.MaterialId equals mat.MaterialId
    join comps in dat2.tblMatComp on mat.MaterialId equals comps.MaterialId
    where locmat.CoLocMatId == obj.CoLocMatId
    select new tblMatComp()
    {
        MatCompId = comps.MatCompId,
        CompQty = comps.CompQty,
        PctByMass = comps.PctByMass,
        PctByVolume = comps.PctByVolume
    }
).ToList();

decimal checkTotal = 0m;

else if (compMeasure == 3) //this is by part
{
    foreach (var x in components)
    {
        //PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS FOR LOOP WORKS AND DOES NOT RETURN ANY ERRORS.
        checkTotal += x.CompQty;
    }

    int i = 0;

    //before we do any database saving, we need to make sure that we are not going to end up with negative inventory for these components.
    foreach (var x in components)
    {

        //PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS IS THE WHILE/FOR LOOP IN QUESTION
        var test = x; //this ends up being null
        var matCompId = x.MatCompId; //this ends up being a null exception as test and x are both null for some reason...

        var compUpd = (
            from inv in dat2.tblInventory
            where (inv.CoLocMatId == matCompId) && (inv.CoLocAreaId == obj.CoLocAreaId)
            select inv
        ).FirstOrDefault();

        if (compUpd == null)
        {
            return "Oops! It looks like we were unable to find an inventory record for one of the components. This is not good, please verify that all components have an inventory record.";
        }
        else
        {
            decimal quantity = (decimal)obj.Qty * (x.CompQty / checkTotal);
            var z = (compUpd.OnHand) - (quantity);

            if (z < 0)
            {
                return "Oops! It looks like performing this inventory transaction will result in a negative amount of inventory for one of the specified components. You may need to add more of one of the components.";
            }

            i++;
        }
    }

   //this is cut off as there is quite a bit more code below this.
```

EDIT:
Adding a screenshot to show that in the second loop, components has values.[image]

EDIT2:
Adding additional screenshots

Also removed the first foreach loop in favor of

`checkTotal = components.Sum(exp => exp.CompQty);`

There is now only 1 foreach loop but the problem is the same. A Null Reference exception is thrown in the foreach loop.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you look at the list in a debugger is every value null or just certain values?  Does it ever get through the list? Can you see a pattern to the null ones? Are they definitely all non-null before the first loop? Is there any code running between the two loops? At what point does your list change?

Comment: If you look at the list in a debugger is every value null or just certain values?  Does it ever get through the list? Can you see a pattern to the null ones? Are they definitely all non-null before the first loop? Is there any code running between the two loops? At what point does your list change?

Comment: @torsan Yes, it is inside of an else-if statement. But so is the first foreach loop, and it works just fine which is what's throwing me off. Components (for the material which I am testing with) has a count of 3, so indexing and iterating should work just fine. For example, checkTotal ends up being 32 as it iterates through the components list just fine.

Comment: @Chris Looking at the information inside of the debugger, I can see values. E.g. while hovering/inspecting "components" in the for loop, I can see three values, each of which has values in it.

Comment: are you saying your collection after the join has some number of values and in each of them there are non null values? also, what is the type that has come out of your collection? i can see you have defined a non anonymous type of `tblMatComp` but just want to rule that out.

Comment: @thanatorr Yes, the collection has 3 values in it, each value has non-null values in it. The types are various as `tblMatComp` has a long list of properties in it. I'm only gathering the ones that I need, e.g. `MatCompId`, `CompQty`, `PctByMass`, `PctByVolume`

Comment: if you are forcing your type to a list then it does not require enumeration to evaluate the items in the collection. therefore if you can loop once and get values and assigned properties then you should be able to do it as many times as you want. are you sure that your `var components` is not disposed of by the garbage collector?

Comment: Then if you are suggestion the collection is built correctly and you are not manually changing the list, i would think that the collection is lost or disposed of somehow. most of the time that shouldn't build but i cant see all of your code.

Comment: Try specifying the type of `test` in your second foreach loop and see what you get. You should know the type of x correct?

Comment: @thanatorr I've updated the original post with a screenshot illustrating the that components variable has values in it.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 I've tried specifying `test` in the second foreach loop, tried while as well, and it ends up being null. But inspecting prior to debug, it does have the appropriate type, which is `tblMatComp`

Comment: try to make a copy of the list for second iteration before first iteration.

Comment: Have you tried running the same code in the first foreach loop? Just the `test` and `matCompID` part?

Comment: @Sudsy1002 Yeah, all of the values are there in the first foreach loop. It seems like when it gets to the second foreach it doesn't want to iterate through.

Comment: @RxNReza That was a good idea. Tried it, but the same thing happened. Still getting a null value for `test` and for `matCompId`

Comment: declare the `FooList` global then inside you first loop `FooList.Add(x)` then try to loop through `FooList` don't create the list inside your loop then it will create a new `List` every time.

Comment: @QuintonChester: This x itself null(I believe and don't think it will be null) or x.MatCompId is null for some tblMatComp objects? Instead of iterating twice can you just take sum of CompQty by using the below code instead of first loop,

checkTotal = components.Sum(exp => exp.CompQty);

foreach (var x in components)
{
     // Same other code
}

Comment: @RxNReza Duplicating the list is fine. I can duplicate it no problem. I don’t think the issue is with the list itself as components and the duplicated version of components have values. It’s that when you iterate a second time it has nothing in it. I’ve tried to do a one line sum and I end up with the same thing. When iterating through, the value for x/test is null.

Comment: @Sivaprasath Thanks for that. I tried the one line sum for checkTotal and it gives the right value (I’ll keep this). But still iterating on the list ends up with x itself being null.

Comment: Can you reupdate the screenshot with breakpoint on x. Very curious to know how x is null. Is it null on the first iteration?

Comment: @Sivaprasath Actually, let me rephrase. x is 0 since it is the iterator in the foreach, but test which is equal to x ends up being null. And then matCompId which is x.MatCompId throws a null reference exception.

Comment: @Sivaprasath Screenshots added.

Comment: What are these objects that you're querying?   Do they happen to be attached to an Entity Framework DbContext by any chance?     I suspect the problem may be with Eager Loading of navigation properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Another possibility, if you are deleting entities as well, is that you may be experiencing a problem related to EF tracking.  if an entity is deleted then EF will update any navigation properties which reference that entity to null.    So if you just want a read-only query, consider using `AsNoTracking`

Comment: Hi @BenCottrell, unfortunately I was not deleting any entities and I was also not running through a DbContext. The queries are executed through use of Telerik OpenAccess.

Comment: @QuintonChester aha, I've never used OpenAccess, but I'm wondering whether the way it handles navigation properties may cause this to happen.   Such "simple" get/set navigation properties in Entity Framework are highly deceptive because the framework overrides those properties with all sorts of magic which can easily trip you over, and result in unexpected null properties or other similar issues.   Perhaps there's some feature of OpenAccess which you might have overlooked?  It's worth exploring anyway.  This doesn't seem like "standard" C# List behaviour to me anyway. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like we went through everything, but I think what this might come down to is a C# limitation? Maybe it's that you cannot perform multiple foreach loops in sequence? Maybe our system was out of memory and could not run through the loops any further? We aren't exactly sure what the cause is, but we did resolve the issue.

**What didn't work:**

- Duplicating the lists, e.g. `components2` and `components3` and iterating through those in the second loops.
- In the first loop, creating a new list with the same information, but using a model with ONLY the values that I would be using.
- Reducing the for loop for the first loop to be a .Sum function. **This was a nice one liner solution to my first loop, it does the same thing, but it tidied the code up a bit. Thanks @Sivaprasath for this**
- Instead of using a foreach loop, using a while loop.
- In the while loop using [i] and .ElementAt(i)
- Using a for loop

**What did work**

- Moving the second and third loops to their own separate functions.

So instead of the second loop, we ended up using the following:

```
var checkInv = CheckInventory(components, checkTotal, obj.CoLocAreaId, (decimal)obj.Qty, compMeasure);
```

and

```
var createUsage = CreateUsageTransactions(components, checkTotal, obj.CoLocAreaId, (decimal)obj.Qty, compMeasure, obj.TransDate, obj.AddResId, obj.AddDate);
```